# on error logging in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Are the below steps enough for the SSIS package to log the error to the log file , 
1) setup connection for the text file to get logged. 2) in the event handler , setup "On error" on the specific executable or the package iteself.

If the answer is yes, then how does SSIS comes to know that the error has to be sent to the log file, as we are not explicitly mentioning it anywhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

The logging is designed to pick up errors in running individual steps of the SSIS package. So if the step to move record to Tablea fails, it would get logged. If there is a step to email someone under certain conditions and that step doesn't work because it can't access the email server that day, then it fails, etc. But you could have a step that check for the existence of the file and you could set it to go to the OnError event if the file does not exist. You could have script that checks the structure of file and causes it to error if the file is not correct. But these are checks you would have to add yourself.

The logging is also not for logging data errors. That is something you have to design for yourself as only the package designer knows what business rules cause the data to be wrong.  We create an exception table to move poor records into and have steps in the packages to check for missing required values, or values that don't match a particular lookup (XA is not a valid state in a US address, for instance.) You would have to determine what type of data cleaning you can do and what type of records you should send to an exception log and run the rest or what types of things would  cause the entire data import or export to fail.

For instance we have some conditions that must be meant before the import of a sales roster can succeed. If one rep doesn't have an email address, we can send that rep to an exception, If 10% of the reps don't have email addresses the package won't process because something clearly is wrong with the file. Another rule that would cause things to fail is if we cannot build the sales hierarchy based on the data sent (a person cannot report to himself for instance!). If the sales person is associated with a product we don't support, for some clients that might fail the entire package (because we know they the messed up what they intended to send) and for some clients it might be that they have requested we ignore those records.

Generally when building an import, my rule of thumb is that you should spend at least 2/3ds of the development time on this sort of thing. This is the Transform part of the ETL process and it is the most critical for long term maintenance of the data.

Comment: Is it enough for the SSIS package to log the error to the log file , if the below 2 are setup.  1) setup connection for the text file to get logged.  2) in the event handler , setup "On error" on the specific executable or the package iteself.       If the answer is yes, then how does SSIS comes to know that the error has to be sent to the log file, as we are not explicitly mentioning it anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough for the SSIS package to log the error to the log file , if the below 2 are setup. 1) setup connection for the text file to get logged. 2) in the event handler , setup "On error" on the specific executable or the package iteself. If the answer is yes, then how does SSIS comes to know that the error has to be sent to the log file, as we are not explicitly mentioning it anywhere in the code